# Visual Studio Namespace Issue

Tags: .net, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I opened a new project and have started to read through the code.  Every XAML page has a reference error:

"The name "IntegerUpDown" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace.Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assemply=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"

The toolkit is referenced with the following:

```
xmlns:iup="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
```

In tool is being used in the XAML like this:

```
<iup:IntegerUpDown Name="txtpromptdelay"/>
```

The iup:IntegerUpDown has a blue squiggly line that references the error.  The XAML will not render because of this error.  I see the Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll in the release folder of the project.  Also, the name "IntegerUpDown" pulls up in intelisence when I type "iup:".

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does the solution build?

Comment: Yes.  It builds with no errors.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Visual Studio?  Sometimes inconsistent behavior like this can be fixed with a restart.  If that doesn't fix it, close Visual Studio, and open up the directory that has the .sln file in it.  There should be a directory in there named ".vs", it may be hidden, so you might have to show hidden files to see it.  Delete that directory.  It contains user level settings, and cached data for the current solution.  It may reset a few things, like your startup project, and which files were open previously, but it *usually* fixes the really strange stuff like you describe.

Comment: Gotta ask anyway, have you cleaned the solution and then did a rebuild?

Comment: Yes.  I cleaned and rebuilt.  I also deleted the .vs hidden folder, started visual studio and cleaned and rebuilt once again.  The error is still there.

Comment: Have you installed Xceed through NuGet?

Comment: No.  I've never heard of NuGet.  I can see the .dll file for Xceed in my bin/release and bind/debug folders.   Wouldn't an installer just create this .dll file?

Comment: The IDE and the build system use different mechanism to locate the dependencies. So in your case, "I see the Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll in the release folder of the project" is obviously a wrong thing. The project should use NuGet or other more suitable approach to indicate the dependency on that assembly, so the IDE can locate the assembly and remove the lines and XAML error. If you never heard of terms like NuGet, well, learn it.

Comment: So... NuGet in .net is equivalent to Maven in Java?